# How to know if an object is created?

Tags: java, object, program-entry-point

I am making a simulator for solving problems in Java. I want to create a task where a person needs to create class A and then in class B, in the main method, create objects of class A. The problem is that I don't know how to check the number of created objects, or at least the fact that objects were created. Can I check the creation of objects? Without making changes to classes A and B ?

```
public class A {
    //some code
}
class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //User will have to create an object of class A here 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of objects created in a class by keeping a `static` variable and increment it upon creation automatically. For example, for class A:

```
class A {
    
    private static int noOfObjects = 0;
    {
        numOfInstances += 1;
    }

    //constructors and other methods

    public static int getNumOfInstances() {
        return numOfInstances;
    }

}
```

**Remember, `static` variables initialized only once, and they're shared between all instances.**

Comment: Yes, but this is a class that the user should make. There should be no code like this there, I wanted to somehow find out the number of objects without making changes to class A and B.